# C++11 get std::map value_type from a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Is there a way to get the [value_type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6ec19ye.aspx) from a variable of type `std::map<K,V>`

For example:

```
class Foo{
    private:
        std::map<int,double> myMap;
    public:
        void Bar(const std::map<int,double>& m)
        {
            using PairType = m::value_type; //How to enable something like this?
            std::vector<PairType> vec(m.size());
            read_ints_and_doubles(&vec, m.size()); //expects a void* (legacy lib I'm using)
        }
};
```

Obviously I know I can use `std::map<int,double>::value_type`, but I want this to be open for future changes.

I thought about using `using MyMapType = std::map<int,double>` and then simply use `MyMapType` everywhere, but I don't want to do that and it seems to me that there is a way to to get this information from the variable itself since this is all static information and I don't see why I can't access this info.

**EDIT:**
This question is far different than the suggested dup: [Declare variables that depend on unknown type in template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888130/declare-variables-that-depend-on-unknown-type-in-template-functions) since I don't try to declare any variable, and the type is known.

Comment: Doesn't `MyMapType::value_type` not work for you?

Comment: oh sorry, I meant that I know it can work with using MyMapType, but I want to do it using the variable

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: Why do you want to get it from the variable? I don't see a reason to  do so.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ,
1 - out of interest since I can't see why there is no way to do this
2 - I don't want to declare any typedefs like MyMapType

Comment: `decltype(myMap)::value_type`

Comment: Why do people down vote without a reason??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare variables that depend on unknown type in template functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888130/declare-variables-that-depend-on-unknown-type-in-template-functions)

Comment: The accepted answer is far different from the answer in the possible duplicate, so this question has not been answered in that previous question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) ([wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xy14LNOsKfcorybE)):

```
using PairType = decltype(m)::value_type;
```

In the above snippet, `decltype(m)` evaluates to the type of `m`.

---

In your particular case, you may want to use [`std::remove_reference_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to remove the reference from the evaluated type - `decltype` does not automatically "decay" the evaluated type.

- C++14 example:

  ```
  using PairType = decltype(m)::value_type;
  std::vector<std::remove_reference_t<PairType>> vec(m.size());
  ```
- C++11 example ([on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V8aQJ8G0mXWNX4WI)):

  ```
  using PairType = decltype(m)::value_type;
  using RemoveRefPairType = typename std::remove_reference<PairType>::type;
  std::vector<RemoveRefPairType> vec(m.size());
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for my example. I get a `error: decltype evaluates to 'const std::map<int, double>&', which is not a class or enumeration type`

Comment: Remove the reference using [`std::remove_reference_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks you very much!

Comment: I thought you meant to remove the reference from the `decltype(m)` but this didn't compile nor does your answer compile, also - I'm using C++11 not C++14 (but event if I define the `_t` myself it doesn't compile

Comment: Oh, for C++11 use: `typename std::remove_reference<PairType>::type`... or just switch to C++14 if you can :)

Comment: Ohh I tried this but forgot to put the `std::` and I didn't even read the compilation error that time :( 
Now it is working perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

decltype will help you here, example:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    using mytype = decltype(m)::value_type;
    mytype r = {1, 5}; // std::pair<const int, int>
}
```