# What else does the condition operator in C++ do for me?

Tags: c++, gcc, conditional-operator

I have got a strange compile error while using condition operator.

`a,b` are `int` value, and the following expression get compile error.

```
(a>b)?( std::cout << a ) : ( b=MAX );
16 (b <unknown operator> 5)' 

(a>b)?( a=MAX ) : ( std::cout<<b );
16 (&std::cout)->std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](b)'
```

But this expression works well, which is odd..

```
(a>b)?( std::cout << a ) : ( std::cout<<b );
```

I have no idea what makes such a difference, and don't know why the compile error stand for. Here is my gcc info:

```
Reading specs from ./../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/specs
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --host=
mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable
-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --e
nable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --without-x --enable-ja
va-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter --enable-hash-synchroniz
ation --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special)`
```

Comment: Putting statements with side effects in a conditional expression looks pretty ugly. Why not use a traditional if-statement?

Comment: @Johannes: I've flagged your comment as unconstructive. Why not a comment that explains why you dislike the question so much, instead of simply being rude?

Comment: @Brennan I think that the questioner knows that very well. I tried to fix it by editing it, but it's incomprehensible. I've never seen a 16 called like a function, and never seen a <unknown operator> be used in C++ (and that's not a GCC diagnostic either). If you don't format your question properly, being on SE for over a year, you need to at least state it in a format that allows other people to format it. That's why I -1'ed. I removed my other comment because I found it's in fact not helpful.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149335/what-is-the-type-of-a-b-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The conditional operator must always return the same type. In your first example,

```
(a > b) ? (std::cout << a) : (b = MAX);
```

the first branch yields the type `std::ostream` and the second branch yields the type of `b` (which is likely an integer, given its context). Your second example,

```
(a > b) ? (std::cout << a) : (std::cout << b);
```

has no such problem because both branches return the same type, `std::ostream`. In either case, it would likely be cleaner to handle these conditions with a simple `if`-`else` statement. The conditional operator tends to hurt readability and is typically only useful when *conditionally* assigning to a variable:

```
int a = (a > b) ? a : b;
std::cout << a;
```

Comment: Just a nit (because globally, your answer is better expressed than mine), but the rules for the types of `b` and `c` in `a ? b : c` are a bit more complicated.  Basically, the compiler must be able to convert one of the types to the other.  So you can have `long` and `int`, or `Base*` and `Derived*` (but not `Derived1*` and `Derived2*`).  Alternatively, one of the expressions can be a `throw` expression, in which case, the type of the expression is the other type.

Comment: In fact, `void *p = 0; (a > b) ? (std::cout << a) : (p = malloc(1));` would be perfectly fine, for example.

Comment: Aother way to fix this is to use the comma operator: `(a > b) ? ((std::cout << a), a) : (b = MAX);` This has the added benefit of making the code even more obscure. ;)

Comment: @James, Johannes: Thanks for making it explicit that types that can be converted to one another are also okay. I should have mentioned that in my answer. I also never considered using a `throw` expression in a conditional operator. It's a horrible idea in terms of readability, but is definitely a fun tidbit that I hadn't considered.

Comment: @Michael Whether the `throw` in a conditional expression is a horrible idea or not depends on context.  It's very useful in initializers in constructors, for example (where you can't use an `if`).

Answer (score 4):

The `?:` is an operator in an expression (or sub-expression).  An expression has a type.  What should the type of `(a > b) ? (std::cout << a) : (b = MAX)` be.  Types in C++ are evaluated statically, and there's no way the compiler can determine a common type for `std::cout << a` (type `std::ostream&`) and `b = MAX` (type `int`).

Comment: Yes, the key here is the part _"An expression has a type"_.

Answer (score 2):

> What else does the condition operator in C++ do for me ?

Well, it does type matching of the second and third arguments, and that can be quite useful as a way of extracting types from expressions. For a mind blowing article on how to use that feature of the conditional operator, read [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html)