# Pointer to overload function

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, overloading, c++11

Let's say, i want to this thing:

```
    std::thread(std::sin,2.9);
```

But i get unresolved function type error. How can i resolve it?
`std::sin` is overloaded, not `template` (why??)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353757/how-do-i-refer-to-stdsinconst-valarraydouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what headers you included, there are the following:

```
template<class T> complex<T>  sin (const complex<T>&);  // <complex>
template<class T> valarray<T> sin (const valarray<T>&); // <valarray>
float sin(float);             // <cmath>
long double sin(long double); // <cmath>
```

As you can see, there *are* templates involved, though that's actually not strictly relevant here.

You simply need to inform the compiler which [potential] overload you want (probably just out of the latter two):

```
std::thread((float(*)(float))&std::sin, 2.9);
```

Comment: If you wish to avoid C-cast, the appropriate C++ cast is `static_cast`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I don't particularly (it's completely superfluous here; what am I going to do, accidentally cast away constness?), but thanks.

Comment: I prefer C++ casts because it's more obvious a cast is going on, subjective, I know :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I prefer not abusing commas!

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
  typedef double (*sind)(double);

  std::thread((sind) std::sin,2.9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the function pointer to the type of the right overload:

```
std::thread((float(*)(float))std::sin, 2.9);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the lambda solution.  It reads much cleaner than anything involving a function pointer.  It will also be faster than using a function pointer, but that doesn't usually matter.

```
std::thread( []( double x ) { return std::sin(x); }, 2.9 );
```